# Unable to use Spring @Cacheable and @EnableCaching

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-data

I'm trying to replace my old:

```java
@Component
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Integer> {

    @QueryHints({@QueryHint(name = CACHEABLE, value = "true")})
    MyEntity findByName(String name);
}
```

by this:

```java
@Component
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Integer> {

    @Cacheable(value = "entities")
    MyEntity findByName(String name);
}
```

Because I want to use advanced caching features like no caching of null values, etc.

To do so, I followed Spring tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/

If I don't annotate my Application.java, caching simply doesn't work.

But if I add `@EnableCaching` and a CacheManager bean:

```java
package my.application.config;

@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"my.application"})
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager("entities");
    }

// ...
}
```

I get the following error at startup:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No CacheResolver specified, and no bean of type CacheManager found.  Register a CacheManager bean or remove the @EnableCaching annotation from your configuration

I get the same error if I replace My CacheManager bean by a CacheResolver bean like:

```java
@Bean
public CacheResolver cacheResolver() {
    return new SimpleCacheResolver(new ConcurrentMapCacheManager("entities"));
}
```

Do I miss something ?

Comment: Implement the `CacheConfigurer` interface. and implement the methods. A bean of that type is needed to properly configure caching.

Comment: Try to name your cacheManager with the name (`entities `) you using in the `@cacheable` annotation.

Comment: @M. Deinum yesterday
What is this `CacheConfigurer` interface ?
It's in no documentation.

Comment: Yes it is. Check the tip/hint [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotation-enable).

Comment: And are you really following that tutorial or are you "following" that tutorial. You have a web application the tutorial doesn't. The tutorial assumes Spring Boot you aren't... So those are quite different things.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

@herau You were right I had to name the bean !
The problem was that there were another bean "cacheManager", so finally, I didn't annotate Application, and created a configuration as:

```
@EnableCaching
@Configuration
public class CacheConf{
    @Bean(name = "springCM")
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager("entities");
    }
}
```

in `MyEntityRepository`:

```
    @Cacheable(value = "entities", cacheManager = "springCM")
    MyEntity findByName(String name);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the Spring Boot library was old, and there was no way to easily upgrade it. So I used EHCache 2 version, and it worked in my application. Here is a project I found useful to refer to: https://github.com/TechPrimers/spring-ehcache-example/blob/master/src/main/resources/ehcache.xml